# Service that will help me visualize SQL db

Tags: database, data, sql

I have a website that I've built and it uses a SQL DB.

I want to be able to view that data, nicely graphed but with the relations made, so that I can keep track of trends over time.

For example I don't just want to be able to look at the trend of users joining over time, I want to know which users did the most of an action, and what they did. This would involve joining several tables.

So, can anyone suggest any tools to assist me in doing this?

Ideally the product/service would import the DB (or access it), I'd specify which tables to join and on which attributes and it would produce the graphs.

I don't want to go the custom route and build the graphs myself. I'd like something I could use there or in another similar situation.

Comment: By "SQL db", do you mean Microsoft SQL Server, or something else like MySQL?

Comment: You should also specify your desktop OS, if locally-installed applications are up for consideration.

Comment: I didn't think that the DB type would make a difference as with databases you can either export them or use ODBC to get access. It's actually mysql if it helps.

Comment: I didn't mention the desktop type because I didn't think it was relevant or necessary. I'm willing to try Windows, Mac, Linux, cloud or anything else I can get my hands on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBVisualizer is a desktop application that has [charting functions](http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/features/index.jsp?feature=22), is cross-platform, and runs against a wide variety of db engines.

Comment: DBVisualizer seems to do the job fairly well so far. Not too expensive too, which is a bonus. Thanks!